# Update all rows in the PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to change in the PhpMyAdmin the text "pelecard" for all fields that contain this text. the table name is sales_flat_order_payment. How I can do this?

[image]
thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is with SQL?

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_payment SET method="123"
```

Then you change all fields to a new value. Without a where clause you change all entries.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done directly in phpMyAdmin. Open the table, choose "Search" then "Find and replace".